# How to add 30 minutes to java.sql.Time object?

Tags: java, time

I have this `Time` object:

```
Time myTime = java.sql.Time.valueOf("15:33:00");
```

How can I add 30 minutes to `myTime` in Java? That means the new time will be 16:03:00

Comment: I'd recommend that you look at the new java.time package if you're using JDK8.  It's easy.

Comment: I can't use it. I have to use java.sql.Time

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? And can you provide more context? Is it possible for you to simply do the time math in the database engine via SQL?

Comment: Start by having a look at [the JavaDocs for java.sql.Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html), from this you can get an instance of [java.time.LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and from there it's a simple matter to add time to

Comment: You have to get it to java.sql.Time eventually, but calculating the long value for epoch time and using it to create java.sql.Time is easy if you use java.time package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 java.sql.Time myTime = java.sql.Time.valueOf("15:33:00");
 LocalTime localtime = myTime.toLocalTime();
 localtime = localtime.plusMinutes(30);
 String output = localtime.toString();
```

you can get localTime straight away from the java.sql.time and you can use plusMinutes in LocalTime Api to add 30 minutes. this might help you check this

Comment: Good answer, except that naming a `LocalTime` object “date” is confusing. Why not call it “localTime”?

Comment: i changed the date to localtime . :D :D

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I need. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do it, using `java.time.LocalDateTime`:

```
package time;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalField;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 4/24/2016.
 * @link
 */
public class TimeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Three three lines do the work
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 4, 24, 9, 10);
        LocalDateTime halfHourLater = localDateTime.plusMinutes(30); // Add 30 minutes
        java.sql.Time sqlDateTime = new java.sql.Time(halfHourLater.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()); //
        // Printout just to check
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS").format(halfHourLater));
        System.out.println("java.time milliseconds: " + halfHourLater.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli());
        System.out.println("System.currentMillis  : " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the use of date-time as seen in this answer. The question was for time-of-day only ([java.sql.Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html))